# Max fake ammo boxes planted?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In Tomb Raider multiplayer, Solarii faction members have the option of planting a fake ammo box explosive. It seems that when I place many of these (by replenishing from wooden crates), some old ones disappear. How many can be layed at one time (by an individual)?

Answer (score 1):

3, 3 is the maximum number of fake ammo boxes that a (Solarii) player can have existing simultaneously.